# Mysql how to convert "2008-08-18 0:00 PST" into a timestamp format?

Tags: mysql

In mysql, how can I convert the string `2008-08-18 0:00 PST` into a timestamp format like `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS`

Comment: Doing a simple string replace on ` PST` -> `:00` would probably accomplish what you want.

Comment: I've read it and tried functions and ways mentioned there -- only problem is the "PST" at the end of my strings. I'm not sure how to have it convert using the timezone.

Comment: These values are from a csv file so I want to accomplish the load in of the csv data using just the load data infile command.

Comment: See my answer below. You could convert the string in an before_filter before adding it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date like this in Ruby:

```
date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
```

If you're want to convert it to a certain timezone, you can combine that with `in_time_zone`

```
date.in_time_zone("London").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
```

I hope that helps. I'm not sure why you want to convert the date in MySQL?

Comment: because i'm importing the data into mysql from a csv file using the mysql "LOAD DATA INFILE" command

Comment: Oh, I understand. Ignore my answer then :)